# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SourceMailbox'

Tags: powershell, office365

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

$group = Read-Host 'What is the Group Mailbox Name?'
$shared = Read-Host 'What is the Shared Mailbox Name?'
$deletedGroup=get-mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox -GroupMailbox -Filter {name -like "$group*"}

$targetuser=get-mailbox -Identity "$shared"

New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox $deletedGroup.DistinguishedName -TargetMailbox $targetuser.DistinguishedName -AllowLegacyDNMismatch -Verbose

Get-MailboxRestoreRequest
```

I get the following error returned:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SourceMailbox'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-MailboxRestoreRequest], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,New-MailboxRestoreRequest
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: The error means that `$deletedGroup.DistinguishedName` doesn't have sensible content. Double-check that the `get-mailbox` that assigns it works as intended.

Comment: as an aside ... this >>> `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` <<< does NOTHING for the script that it is in. [*grin*] you need to set that _before_ the script is run OR with the command that starts the script.